# Matlab: read XML with multiple of childs?

Tags: xml, matlab

Here my 'C1.xml' file:

```
<!DOCTYPE GroundTruth>
<dataset name="camera1">
 <frame number="00000000"/>
 <frame number="00000001"/>
 <frame number="00000002"/>
 <frame number="00000003"/>
 <frame number="00000004"/>
.
.
.
 <frame number="00000233">
  <person id="0001">
   <leftEye x="626" y="210"/>
   <rightEye x="643" y="214"/>
  </person>
 </frame>
 <frame number="00000234">
  <person id="0003">
   <leftEye x="619" y="211"/>
   <rightEye x="636" y="215"/>
  </person>
 </frame>
 <frame number="00000235">
  <person id="0025">
   <leftEye x="613" y="213"/>
   <rightEye x="630" y="216"/>
  </person>
 </frame>
 <frame number="00004403"/>
 <frame number="00004404"/>
 <frame number="00004405"/>
 <frame number="00004406"/>
 <frame number="00004407"/>
 <frame number="00004408"/>
 <frame number="00004409"/>
</dataset>
```

My incomplete code:

```
xDoc = xmlread('C1.xml');

allListitems = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('frame');

frameL = allListitems.getLength;

for k = 0:frameL-1
    thisElement = allListitems.item(k);
    thisList = thisElement.getElementsByTagName('person');
    if (thisList.getLength~=0)
        thisElement = thisList.item(0);
        % problem is here where I also don't know what type of data findCbk 
        % have (char or ...??)

        findCbk = char(thisElement.getFirstChild.getData);

    end
end
```

I want to get the frame number with corresponding person id and the data for leftEye and rightEye. So, if I `sprintf findCbk`, it will give me numbers that I can't relate for `%d` and empty for `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

So here the answer. The thing that I need is `getAttribute`. So I write down the code if someone having the same problem or if someone can correct me if I was wrong.

```
xDoc = xmlread('C1.xml');
allListitems = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('frame');

frameL = allListitems.getLength;

for k = 0: frameL-1
    thisElement = allListitems.item(k);
    frameNum = (char(thisElement.getAttribute('number')))

%check the child inside element frame
thisList = thisElement.getElementsByTagName('person');
face = thisList.getLength;
if (face~=0)
    thisElement = thisList.item(0);
    personID = (char(thisElement.getAttribute('id')))
        eyeL = thisElement.getElementsByTagName('leftEye');
                        thisElementl = eyeL.item(0);
                xL = (char(thisElementl.getAttribute('x')))
                yL = (char(thisElementl.getAttribute('y')))

        eyeR = thisElement.getElementsByTagName('rightEye');
                       thisElementr = eyeR.item(0);
                xR = (char(thisElementr.getAttribute('x')))
                yR = (char(thisElementr.getAttribute('y')))
    break 
end
end
```

It will return:

```
frameNum =

00000000

frameNum =

00000001    

frameNum =

00000002
.
.
.
.       
frameNum =

00000230 

frameNum =

00000231

frameNum =

00000232

frameNum =

00000233

personID =

0003

xL =

626    

yL =

210

xR =

643

yR =

214
```